# How to reuse UIViews, the way UITableView does?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to create a view that shows vast amounts of data. Using `UITableView` would have been a good idea except it's not the way/style I want to show it. I'm thinking of creating my own view, and I was wondering: `UITableViewCell` is constantly being reused through the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method; how does this work? I mean, I can figure out how to cache `UIView`s, but how does `UITableView` draws them on the table, allowing them to still be interactive, without keeping the `UIView`s themselves?

Thanks!
Aviad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's [ScrollViewSuite sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) shows how to create a tiled UIScrollView that reuses views very much like a table view. You could use it as a model or starting point.

Comment: `UICollectionView` is likely worth a look too.